# How to find all users who wrote code in particular file in Git?

Tags: git, github, github-codereviews

How to get the list of all users who contributed for this one file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find most of this by reading the online help for `git log` (and the deduplication step is basic shell knowledge, assuming you have something like a reasonable shell).

1. get the list of all commits affecting the file:

   `git log -- filename`
2. format the commits so only the author is printed:

   `git log --pretty=format:%an -- filename`
3. make sure effective no-op commits are not pruned, if that matters:

   `git log --pretty=format:%an --full-history -- filename`
4. deduplicate

   `git log --pretty=format:%an --full-history -- filename | sort -u`

Comment: You might also want to throw `--all` in to cover for other branches than the currently checked out one. But not necessarily, as it depends on your workflow.